# mush instead of signal stm32 nucleo-l053r8

Tags: stm32, arm, c++, nucleo

Generating a triangular signal. The "printf" line is commented out. If the "printf" line is uncommented, instead of a signal, mush.
How to fix it? (stm32 nucleo-l053r8)

````
#include "mbed.h"
#if !DEVICE_ANALOGOUT
#error You cannot use this example as the AnalogOut is not supported on this device.
#else
AnalogOut my_output(PA_4);
AnalogIn analog_value(A0);
DigitalOut led(LED1);
#endif
#define RANGE (0xFFFF)
#define BUFFER_SIZE (256)
float AMPLITUDE=0;

uint16_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

void calculate_sinewave(void);

float meas_r;
float meas_v;

int main() {
calculate_sinewave(); //generating a triangular signal
while(1) {
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
float arg = buffer[i];
my_output.write_u16(arg);

meas_r = analog_value.read(); // get the value from the ADC port (value from 0,0 to 1,0 = full range ADC)
meas_v = meas_r * 3300; // Converts a value in a range 0В-3,3В

//output the value to the "Terminal" program
//uncommented="mush"
//printf("measure = %f = %.0f mV %f \n\r)", meas_r, meas_v, arg);

    if (meas_v < 300) //if the meas_v value is less than N mV, the LED lights up
    {
        led = 0; // LED ON
    } else {
        led = 1; // LED OFF
    }

wait_us(100); //delay for the eye to see the blinking of the LED
}}}
void calculate_sinewave(void){
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE / 2; i++) {
AMPLITUDE+=(0.00244);
buffer[i] = (uint16_t)(AMPLITUDE*(RANGE));
}
for (int i = BUFFER_SIZE / 2; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
AMPLITUDE-=(0.00244);
buffer[i] = (uint16_t)(AMPLITUDE*(RANGE));
}
}```
````

Comment: you mention triangular wave but the code mentions sine wave. Which is it?

Comment: @Kartman calculate_sinewave generating a triangular signal, watch function

Comment: Describing your signal as "mush" is not helpful. Show us oscilloscope traces of good and bad outputs. Translate comments into English. Indent your code properly. Add description of the signal parameters: amplitude, frequency, offset and so forth.

Comment: `printf` is a slow, likely blocking statement. If it is going to a serial connection, each call will likely take 3ms (=3000us). Compared to the delay of 10us in your main loop, this of course messes up the timing completely.

Comment: @Codo I agree. How to fix it? I don't know

Comment: There's no easy fix. Options are: (1) Implement non-blocking serial output and only print something 10 times a second. It will still affect the output. (2) Use DMA to output the signal. Not trivial, but probably the only solid solution. (3) Don't use text debug output. Only use GPIO signals for debugging.

Comment: @Codo printf is required to output values to the Terminal program on requestment. It can be deleted, but then a replacement is needed, otherwise the task is not considered completed.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I did it. I don't have access to an oscilloscope right now. Not taking a photo of the signal was stupid, I agree. Fix the comments.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson @Codo @Kartman Maybe can use `outport` (dos.h)? Or `sprintf`?

Comment: *sprintf* doesn't solve your issue. It only formats a string. So you still need non-blocking serial output, DMA or similar to send the string somewhere. And *sprintf* isn't the fasted function either. So it might already be too much for a simple implementation without DMA. (I'm not familiar with *outport*. Does it exist on STM32 at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: reduce oscilloscope scale frequency.The signal will build up slowly but retain its shape.

[image]